# Incorrect frame rate in video (Xuggler + MPEG 4 + H.264)

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, h.264, xuggler

I have a problem with incorrect value of frame rate in output file, after converting. I made a really simple example to describe a problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // reader
    IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("/tmp/1/i3.avi");
    IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("/tmp/1/o3.mp4", reader);
    reader.addListener(writer);

    while (true) {
        try {
            final IError error = reader.readPacket();
            if(error != null) {
                System.err.println("Error decoding packet " + error.getDescription());

                if (!reader.isOpen()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error decoding packet " + ex.getMessage());
            if (!reader.isOpen()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any additional parameters for video or audio streams/codecs aren't configured .

The input video file ("/tmp/1/i3.avi") has the following features:

- General

  - Container: Audio Video Interleave (AVI)
- Video

  - Dimensions: 624x352
  - Codec: XVID MPEG-4
  - Framerate: **24 frames per second**
  - Bitrate: N/A
- Audio:

  - Codec: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3)
  - Channels: Stereo
  - Sample rate: 48000 Hz
  - Bitrate: 112 kbps

The output video file ("/tmp/1/o3.avi") has the following features:

- General

  - Container: Quicktime
- Video

  - Dimensions: 624x352
  - Codec: H.264
  - Framerate: **8 frames per second**
  - Bitrate: 378 kbps
- Audio:

  - Codec: MPEG-4 AAC
  - Channels: Stereo
  - Sample rate: 48000 Hz
  - Bitrate: 127 kbps

So, the frame rate in output file is 8 instead of 24. How can I fix it? Please, help me..

PS: I've already tried [Xuggler H264 FPS encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217088/xuggler-h264-fps-encoding-issue) and few another solutions, it doesn't help..

---

**UPD:** After a long war with Xugler I wrote my own pure-java interface to the avconv and it works fine for me: https://github.com/vbauer/avconv4java

Comment: I just stumbled over JavaCV. Looks impressive. JNI bindings, available on maven central incl. a 135 pkg containing platform-dependent, likely optimized binaries.